# Bind to simple array of strings

Tags: knockout.js, jquery-templates

If I want to bind a template to a plain old array of strings, what do I put in the ${??} expression?

I hope this snippet isn't too short so as to confuse:

```
<ul data-bind="template: { name: 'authorTemplate', foreach: authors }">
</ul>
```

where authors is simply `["a", "b", "c"]`

```
<script type="text/x-jquery-tmpl" id="authorTemplate">
    <li>${what_do_I_put_here???}</li>
</script>
```

I've tried: `val` `value` `this` and `this.toString()`.  The last two displayed [object Object] so I suspect I'm pretty close there.

Answer (score 107, accepted):

[From the documentation](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html#note-1-referring-to-each-array-entry-using-data), the answer is:

When using a template:
`${$data}`

When not using a template:
`$data`

Comment: An explanation of $data or links to documentation would help would be googlers.

Comment: I can't seem to find that—I got this answer from their google group.  Do you by chance have a link?

Comment: Afraid not, but presume it is in the jQuery templates documentation, or else (if it is specific to knockoutjs) in the knockoujs docs.

Comment: The `foreach` documentation has a relevant [example](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/foreach-binding.html)

Comment: If not using templates, it would be `<ul data-bind='foreach: array'><li data-bind='text: $data'>...`

Comment: @awrigley http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/click-binding.html `Note 1: Passing a “current item” as a parameter to your handler function`

Comment: Knockout binds arrays by calling toString() on each member and then doing .join(", ").

Answer (score 51):

For unnamed array (JSON like: ["value1", "value2"]), it would be:

```
<ul data-bind="foreach: $root">
 <li data-bind="text: $data"></li>
</ul>
```

$root keyword does the trick.

Comment: Yeah - the above code was for use with jQuery templates.  Having ditched that long ago and went with the native knockout templates, this indeed how to do it.

Comment: Actually, `$root` represents the object passed to `ko.applyBindings`. So this would only work if you did something like `ko.applyBindings(["value1", "value2"], document.getElementById("MyValueList"));`. If you're going to be binding anything else on the page, you would be better served having this as a named member on your viewmodel, or you could write the array to the binding like so: `foreach: ["value1", "value2"]`. See http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/binding-context.html for more info.