# knockout foreach iteration through an array of strings

Tags: knockout.js

I found this, but this doesn't work for me: [Bind to simple array of strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7248719/bind-to-simple-array-of-strings)

I am just trying to manage an array of strings through knockout. Here is my markup:

```
<div class="editor-field">
        <table>
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Page Urls</th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <!-- ko if: RouteUrls().length > 0 -->
            <tbody data-bind="foreach: RouteUrls">                   
                <tr>
                    <td><span data-bind="text: $data"></span></td>
                    <td><a href="#" class="ui-icon ui-icon-closethick" data-bind="click: $root.removeUrl">Remove</a></td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <!-- /ko -->
            <!-- ko if: RouteUrls().length < 1 -->
            <tbody>
                <tr>    
                    <td colspan="3"> No urls added for editing.</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
            <!-- /ko -->
        </table>
        @Html.HiddenFor(x => x.UrlCount, new { data_bind = "value:RouteUrls().length" })
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.UrlCount)
    </div>
```

And here is my knockout code:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mappedModel = ko.mapping.fromJS(@Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(Model)));
    mappedModel.RouteUrls = ko.observableArray([]);
    mappedModel.urlToAdd = ko.observable("/");
    mappedModel.addUrl = function() {
        var duplicateValues = ko.utils.arrayFilter(this.RouteUrls(), function (item) {
                return item == mappedModel.urlToAdd();                   
        });

        if ((this.urlToAdd() != "") && (duplicateValues.length == 0)) // Prevent blanks and duplicates
        {

            this.RouteUrls().push(this.urlToAdd());
            this.urlToAdd("/");
            console.log(this.RouteUrls().length);
            console.log(this.RouteUrls());
        }
    };
    mappedModel.removeUrl = function(url) {
        mappedModel.RouteUrls.remove(url);
    };

    //other code...

    ko.applyBindings(mappedModel);

    $.validator.unobtrusive.parse("#pageCForm");
    $("#pageForm").data("validator").settings.submitHandler = mappedModel.save;
</script>
```

Now the problem is, in my markup, the collection never shows. When I try and add a url, even if I remove the knockout if conditional and just display the table, it is always empty. If I try and submit the page, I have unobtrusive validation running on the hidden field for URL count and it acts like it's empty too. So everything in the markup is acting like `RouteUrls()` is always empty. But when I log the RouteUrls().length and text to the console I get the following after successive attempts to add:

```
1 
["/sdfsd"] 
2 
["/sdfsd", "/trgfd"] 
3 
["/sdfsd", "/trgfd", "/fdfdggdbjn"]
```

So I don't understand how in the script code the length and array are properly getting populated, but it's not being reflected in the markup. Any help?

Comment: Have you called ko.applyBinding(mappedModel);?

Comment: Yes sorry I just didn't include it in the pasted code...I'll update it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is (probably) on this line :

```
this.RouteUrls().push(this.urlToAdd());
```

Knockout redefined the push (and every other methods that change an array) in the ObservableArray. These ObservableArray methods will change the array **and then trigger the observers**.

So you should replace it with :

```
this.RouteUrls.push(this.urlToAdd());
```

More infos here :
http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/observableArrays.html#manipulating_an_observablearray

Comment: Gahh can't believe I didn't catch that, so simple yet so easily missed. Thanks!